# Installshield 2011 disk spanning 

Tags: installshield

I have a multi-parted installer which contains cab files data1.cab, data2.cab, data3.cab and data4.cab. But some users found that when the data3.cab is corrupted(normally the fille size is 1900MB, but the corrupted one is only more than 300KB), the installer prompts to insert a disk which contains data5.cab, which doesn't exist. So i wonder how installshield does the disk spanning work and there is any way to validate the cab file first.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this problem before.  The only problems I'm aware of is you have to burn the CD/DVD to have a volume label that matches what's in the Media table and if you have an _ in the feature name and compress 1 CAB per Feature the short/long filename conversion can get messed up.  Otherwise I've been some really big installs over the years and not had a problem with cabbing.

Are you sure your installer built successfully?  Are you having any CM problems between when the build is complete and your media is mastered?

The CAB file should be able to be opened using WinZip.

Comment: Actully we dont release our product through dvd or cd but put it on our website for user to download. So there is a good chance the the user get corrupted cabs. And we want to validate the cabs first before actual installing. Any idea how to do it elegantly?

Comment: One easy way would be to digitally sign your msi and cabs.  If the file is corrupted, the signature will be invalidated.